# What are the differences between a *string and a string in Golang?

Tags: string, go

**Aim:** understanding the difference between `*string` and `string` in Golang

---

**Attempt**

```
func passArguments() {
    username := flag.String("user", "root", "Username for this server")
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Printf("Your username is %q.", *username)
    fmt.Printf("Your username is %q.", username)
}
```

results in:

```
Your username is "root".Your username is %!q(*string=0xc820072200)
```

but when the *string is assigned to a string:

```
bla:=*username
fmt.Printf("Your username is %q.", bla)
```

it is able to print the string again:

```
Your username is "root".Your username is %!q(*string=0xc8200781f0).Your username is "root".
```

---

**Questions**

1. Why is a *string != string, e.g. display of: `"root"` vs.
   `%!q(*string=0xc8200781f0)`?
2. In what other cases should a *string be
   used instead of a string and why?
3. Why is it possible to assign a
   *string to a string variable, while the display of the string is different, e.g. display of: `"root"` vs.
   `%!q(*string=0xc8200781f0)`?

Comment: Variables denoted with a * are pointers, or an address in memory (think of it as a mailing address where a variable is a house). Refer to https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1 for more.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A `*string` is a pointer to a string. If you're not familiar with pointers, let's just say that it's a value that holds the address of another value, instead of the value itself (it's a level of indirection).

When a `*` is used in a type, it denotes a pointer to that type. `*int` is a pointer to an integer. `***bool` is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a bool.

`flag.String` returns a pointer to a string because it it can then modify the string value (after the call to `flag.Parse`) and you are able to retrieve that value using the dereference operator - that is, when using `*` on a variable, it *dereferences* it, or retrieves the value pointed to instead of the value of the variable itself (which in the case of a pointer would just be a memory address).

So to answer your specific questions:

1. the `%q` verb in the `fmt` package understands strings (and slices of bytes), not pointers, hence the apparent gibberish displayed (when a value is not of the expected type for the matching verb - here `%q` - the `fmt` functions display `%!q` along with the actual type and value passed)
2. A pointer to a string is very rarely used. A string in Go is immutable (https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types) so in cases like `flag.String` where you need to return a string that will be mutated later on, you have to return a pointer to a string. But you won't see that very often in idiomatic Go.
3. You are not assigning a `*string` (pointer to a string) to a `string`. What you are doing, as I mentioned earlier, is **dereferencing** the `*string` variable, extracting its `string` value. So you are in fact assigning a `string` to a `string`. Try removing the `*` on that line, you'll see the compiler error message. (actually, because you're using the short variable declaration notation, `:=`, you won't see a compiler error, but your variable will be declared as a pointer-to-a-string. Try this instead, to better understand what's going on:

   ```
   var s string
   s = username
   ```

That will raise the compiler error).